# mysql time format to get only hours and minutes

Tags: mysql

I am struggling with the syntax for a MYSQL query.

I am currently just grabbing all fields via `select * from TABLENAME`.
It works but the fields that are `type=time` come back with this format:
01:14:00.000000
Is there a way for format the query to just get a 24hr time (only hours and minutes)?

Comment: You want to format time as desired string format?

Comment: Remember that this is often best done in your application as time formatting preferences vary wildly from one user to the next. Some prefer `10:23pm`, others `22h23` and that's just two examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at [time_format](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/time_format.php)?

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(`TABLENAME.TIME`, '%H %i'), `OTHERFIELDS` FROM TABLENAME;
```

Code is untested, but should work.

Comment: I get a syntax error when running (exact statement): SELECT TIME_FORMAT(`timedispatched`, "%H %i"), * FROM webform1;

Comment: oh, you need to do this: `SELECT TIME_FORMAT(timedispatched, "%H %i"), webform1.* FROM webform1;`

Answer (score 0):

```
select TIME_FORMAT(`TABLENAME.TIME`, '%H:%i') as column_name FROM TABLENAME;
```